# How to check if an update is done by Rest API or Bulk API

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api

We have a 3rd party system which updates records in our salesforce org on a daily basis. Is there a way to check if this system is using Rest API or Bulk API? The developer mentioned it runs on Roby using [Restforce](https://restforce.github.io/#learn-more), from the name it sounds like it's Rest but I have to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mention of the bulk API in the documentation or obviously in the code.

Post your question here https://github.com/restforce/restforce/issues for an answer from the community that works on Restforce.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Event Monitoring licensed, you can see API calls for a given time range and various other fields per the Event Monitoring record types:

- [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_restapi.htm)
- [Bulk API 2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_bulkapi2.htm)
- [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_bulkapi.htm)

For example, you can filter based on `UserId`, `Timestamp`, or `ClientIp` to help ascertain what you are receiving.  The Event Monitoring license comes with a free Event Monitoring App (Built on Salesforce CRM) with instantly useful drill-down dashboards